# CSS grid - responsive gallery

Tags: css, responsive, css-grid

is there a way how to make gallery with CSS grid with following requirements?

1. Gallery should always fill entire container and is responsive
2. Gap between images is fixed
3. Every image has limited maximum and minimum size (e.g. 200px - 260px)

Code for gallery is following (span represents image in this example):

```css
/* Container */
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0.25em;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
/* Image placeholder */
span {
    display: block;
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
/* Aspect ratio */
span:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
    <div class="item"><span></span></div>
</div>
```

When there are enough items, everything works just fine. But when gallery has only few of them, items are stretched and image becomes blurry and looks terrible. In that case, there should be behavior as with auto-fill used.

We have tried following, but none of these solutions is good enough:

- Use `auto-fill` instead of `auto-fit` *(images tend to be as little as possible instead of as big as possible)*
- Limit size of single image *(gaps become uneven)*
- Use `minmax(200px, 260px)` instead of `minmax(200px, 1fr)` *(gallery is not filling entire container)*

Do anyone have any idea how to solve that? Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use `auto-fill` instead of `auto-fit`

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 0.25em;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
```

Comment: I've mentioned this solution at the end of my question, this unfortunately tries to fit as many images on each line as possible, but we need as little as possible (because bigger images are better than smaller).

Comment: Then you should increase the width 200px to even higher in minmax

Comment: But then will size of image go beyond 260px on some resolutions.

Comment: `minmax(200px, 1fr)` > if you want image to grow but not shrinking below 200px

`minmax(1fr,200px)` > if you want image to shrink but not grow above 200px

Comment: No, unfortunately `minmax(1fr, 200px)` is causing grid to have only single column with both `auto-fit` and `auto-fill`. Generally, `1fr` as first parameter of `minmax` function is useless.